# Arranging UIButtonViews from Left To Right in OAStackView with Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

Possibly a very dumb question but how do I arrange views (UIButtonViews in my case) from left to right rather than top to bottom using OAStackView in Interface Builder on Xcode 7. I expected to see something like 'horizonal' and 'vertical' checkboxes. Is this only doable from code?

P.S. We have no OAStackView tag on StackOverflow at the moment

Comment: Try this:- https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on my own question, I posted a question on [github on OAStackView's repo](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView/issues/57) and got this reply:

> since IB does not really support "enums" as IBInspectable properties, you have to set 0 or 1 in axisValue in IB.

OAStackView's [README.md](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView) has been updated to reflect this now.